# How to add string values using apex?

Tags: apex, string, number

I have two string values using numbers. How to add(not concatenate) the two string values. Could you please help me.

### my code:

```
string num='2016';
system.debug('first:'+num);
Output: 2016

string num1='2016'+'1';
system.debug('second:'+num1);
Output: 20161
```

But I need 2017.Is it possible or not this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Integer num = Integer.valueOf('2006');
Integer num2 = Integer.valueOf('1');

Integer result = num + num2;
System.debug(result);
```

Update as per comment, to transform it to a String:

```
String str = String.valueOf(result);
System.debug(str);
```

Comment: i would however put that in a try/Catch block when you do that as you may throw a conversion error if the values are not formatted properly as numbers that you are trying to parse.

Comment: for brevity I have omitted try/catch

Comment: I understand - just thought i would comment it for other users to benefit as well.

Comment: @Santanu Boral, Thankyou for quick reply. The above scenario is working fine. But in the this way I am using string. The same output get using string or not?  If possible could you please explain me

Comment: you can get it to a string using String str = String.valueOf(result);
System.debug(str);

Comment: @Santanu Boral, Thankyou. I know that way, But is it possible any another ways?

Comment: that's the simple way I can think of. Otherwise, wait for some other person to chime in

Comment: If my answer solved your purpose then accept this, so that others may find this useful